# Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched

Tags: android, gradle, bitbucket-pipelines

I've just setup a Bitbucket pipeline to build an Android application in a Docker container ...

but after the build, it fails to mount some unknown directory:

```
> Task :mobile:lintDebug
Wrote HTML report to file:///opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/mobile/build/reports/lint-results-debug.html
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 51s
41 actionable tasks: 41 executed
Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched.
The whole state of the virtual file system has been discarded.
Reason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
```

What's the reason for this / how to get rid of that error message?

Comment: If you are just running a build from clean in this job, you can turn the watching off with `--no-watch-fs`

Comment: @tim_yates When locally running with `--debug` it shows that it tries to watch all mounted file-systems, when it's done building (this most likely is being disabled while building on purpose)... while in this situation, the file-systems apparently had already been unmounted already (there's a race condition). `--no-watch-fs` appears to be applicable; sounds promising.